# Copy Paste In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

This is an age-old question, but I'm still having trouble with it. You see, I'm trying to paste some Excel data in a Text Area, but the silly browsers freeze for long periods of time when doing this, because of God-knows-what "smart" parsing they do. I can't get rid of that (file upload is out of the question, my boss wants me to paste rows from Excel in a Text Area).

The good news is that pasting in a standard textbox WORKS. But I can't force them to paste there. So I am trying to catch the paste event in the Text Area and then throw the text over to the textbox. Unfortunately, I stopped short at the pasting part. I can't paste the text via JS into the simple textbox.

So my question is: how do you paste a text, how do you invoke it via JS? There are some solutions which only work in IE, that's not good, of course ::- ).

Comment: The regular textbox is faster because it only holds one line (duh).

Comment: Duh of course. But it still pastes Excel data ok, separated by tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, didn't quite catch the idea. Can't you attach to thextarea's `onpaste` event (at least I know IE has such event) and then simply set textarea's value to the pasted value?

```
    pastedContent = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
    document.getElementById("yourtextarea").value = pastedContent;
```

EDIT: ok, it seems like this only works in IE and [newer versions of FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.onpaste), but it's not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: This is an IE-only solution ::- (

Answer (score 6):

Simple.

```js
var isIe = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1 
            || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident") != -1);

document.getElementById('textinput').addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    var text;
    
    if (isIe) {
        text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text')   
    } else {
        text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }
    
    // Do whatever you want with the text
    console.log(text);
    
    //If you don't want the text pasted in the textarea
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textinput"></textarea>
```

If you want, you can even get rid of the textarea and do this more directly. I wrote a technical [blog post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/) explaining how we do copying and pasting at Lucidchart (where I work).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't paste the text via JS into the simple textbox

When you say “simple textbox”, do you mean `<input type="text">`? If so, then I think setting its `value` attribute to the text you’ve captured from the `<textarea>` should work.

Comment: as far as I understand, the problem is catching the "paste" event in a cross-browser manner

Comment: I can catch the paste event, but not the pasted data. There are some commands like ExecCommand but they only work in IE.

Comment: Ah. How about: 1. Let the paste event complete in the `<textarea>`. 2. Read the `value` attribute of the textarea to get the pasted text. 3. Set the `value` of the `<textarea>` to an empty string. 4. Set the `value` of the normal text field to the text you got in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Enable  javascript Copy to Clipboard in Firefox or Mozilla: http://www.febooti.com/support/website-help/website-javascript-copy-clipboard.html

Comment: this is not a solution as you can't control users' FF settings remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) as alternate solution. Doesn't check it with copy&paste with huge/excel amount of data but maybe this help...